# Recover lost data due to delete in PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database, and recently a new table called 'conferences' was created, which had a foreign key (FK) referencing the 'orders' table. A delete operation was performed within the 'conferences' table, and due to the cascade delete, it also deleted the information in the 'orders' table. I would like to know if there is any way to recover this data, considering that I don't have a backup of this information.

I tried searching for other solutions on the internet, but I didn't find any. I looked into checkpoints, but it wasn't very clear.

Comment: No backup means almost probably that deleted data are gone.

Comment: no backup = worthless data. You might be able to find somebody who can recover some data from disk, but without any guarantees! Other processes might have overwritten these memory blocks already. Turn off your server asap, or accept the loss.

Answer (score 0):

Once delete executed in PostgreSQL database, you have very little to no chances to recover your data without backup.
What happening when delete record happening in PostgreSQL:

- PostgreSQL will mark records that matches to criteria as deleted records, but not physically delete them.
- From now deleted rows can be found with you SELECTs, but the still inside the table (aka Dead Tuples).
- Autovacuum demon will kick in sometime later and physically delete marked rows.

After Autovacuum you won't be able to get access to "deleted" rows. 
Before that you need some extra tools to access "deleted" records. One tool I can suggest is [pageinspect extension](https://pageinspect). Its quite advanced tool but you can query deleted records and store it somewhere.